# Unknown error in my Project

Tags: fonts, missing

I have now obtained a correct installation of XeLaTeX but I'm missing some fonts:

How do I install fonts from slabikar.tfm and slabikar.sty files ?
Now I'm getting the following error.

```
Command Line:   xelatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "ideje.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./ideje.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-11-22>
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/accents/accents.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.def
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))
))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.cod
e.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.c
ode.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
 (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.st
y)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.st
y)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarytopaths.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tikz-cd/tikzlibrarycd.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarymatrix.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
braryquotes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.meta.cod
e.tex))) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/xebabel.def
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-czech/czech.ldf))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty

Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/cslatex/base/il2enc.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/il2lmr.fd))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/skak/skak.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chessfss/chessfss.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chessfss/lsbenc.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chessfss/lsfenc.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chessfss/lsienc.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/plain/lambda-lists/lambda.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chessfss/lsbskaknew.fd)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/il2lmss.fd)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `IL2/lmss/m/up' undefined
(Font)              using `IL2/lmss/m/n' instead on input line 1774.

) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
(|extractbb --version))))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xltxtra/xltxtra.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/realscripts/realscripts.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/metalogo/metalogo.sty)) (./mypackage.sty)
 (./babyloniannum.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
*** you should *not* be loading the inputenc package
*** XeTeX expects the source to be in UTF8 encoding
*** some features of other encodings may conflict, resulting in poor output.
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/numname/numname.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty) (./ideje.aux)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chessfss/lsfskaknew.fd)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chessfss/lsiskaknew.fd)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
*** you should *not* be loading the inputenc package
*** XeTeX expects the source to be in UTF8 encoding
*** some features of other encodings may conflict, resulting in poor output.
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd)
Missing character: There is no š ("161) in font slabikar!
Missing character: There is no ř ("159) in font slabikar!
Missing character: There is no ž ("17E) in font slabikar!
Missing character: There is no ř ("159) in font slabikar!
Missing character: There is no ě ("11B) in font slabikar!
Missing character: There is no č ("10D) in font slabikar!
Missing character: There is no č ("10D) in font slabikar!
[1]

! LaTeX Error: \begin{enumerate} on input line 179 ended by \end{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.208 \end{document}
                    
? ^C
Type <return> to proceed, S to scroll future error messages,
R to run without stopping, Q to run quietly,
I to insert something, E to edit your file,
1 or ... or 9 to ignore the next 1 to 9 tokens of input,
H for help, X to quit.
? X
fwrite: Invalid argument
xelatex.exe: 

_____________________________________________________________________

 XeLaTeX Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 1   Warnings: 2   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: The main issue is `! LaTeX Error: \begin{enumerate} on input line 179 ended by \end{document}.` Please post a compilable code producing the error..

Comment: I have now succeeded in obtaining my ideje.pdf file! Where can I find the MainMenu.ini in Winedt10.3 to set shortcuts (F9) and display it as a part of a tree on the LHS ?

Comment: you should not be using inputenc with xetex and should not be using fontenc and specifying legacy 8-bit encodings. Either use 8bit tex font packages with pdflatex or use xelatex with Unicode fonts.

Comment: the document you have is clearly written for pdflatex (even though you have not shown it), are you sure you want to use xelatex?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the document uses fontspec, and fontenc seems to be used for chess encodings, so xelatex is probably okay, but the loading order is wrong.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer perhaps but if the OP chooses not to show the document I give up:-)